# Not able to install Hadoop in Google Compute Engine

Tags: hadoop, google-compute-engine

When I am trying to "Deploy Apache Hadoop" from google compute engine , i am getting a message as "Deployment would exceed CPU quota for us-central1. Limit: 8. Decrease usage, select a zone in another region, or request a quota increase." I tried with all the Zone. Its still not working.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the GCE Free trial, you are limited to 8 concurrent CPU cores. This is true for all regions and zones so trying in a different zone will not solve this problem.

To run a larger deployment, you need to upgrade to a paid account. Alternatively, you can use [Google Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/) or [`bdutil`](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bdutil) to [deploy a Hadoop cluster](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/setting-up-a-hadoop-cluster) and choose a few, smaller instance types such that you are not using more than 8 CPU cores.

You can see [how many cores are in each machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) to help you decide how to structure your cluster.

Comment: It worked after having it as Paid account.  So for the installation we need more that 8 CPU cores.